# Ghost of Arch Linux -- ERROR: (Code: ENOTFOUND)

Tags: linux, installation, ghost

> ERROR: (Code: ENOTFOUND)  There was an error starting your server. 
>   Please use the error code above to search for a solution.

I tried same code on Ubuntu and Fedora, and it worked all fine. But when running on Arch Linux, it gives the above error. What could be the problem?

Comment: Please post the code that caused the error.

Comment: Somhow this just got solved. Thanks user1766169